# I am a python student, and I have a problem

Tags: python

```
def thing():
_list = [1,1,5,6,8,3,4,6,10,23,5,12,67,3,25,2,6,5,4,3,2,1]
_list1 = [str(i) for i<=5 in lista]
return " ".join(_list1)

print(thing()))
```

I am new to this type of list managment, I am trying to put in _list1 only integers that are less then 5

Comment: Do you get any error. Also, is your real code indented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so like the name of your function, it's created to calculate the sum of integers.
So basically, if your **n=0** then your program will return 0 as result.
If not (**else**), it gonna give you a result of the calculation in return.
And here you want to print the **interger sum** of 451 which will give you the result of `n % 10 + integer_sum(int(n / 10))`

Comment: Yeah, thank you, maybe i didn't specify, I probably meant to say that i am more interested in how the calculation works, but I appreciate the answer :3